# How to hide method by route but not effect other method

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have a login method under Student controller with a class param, the login url is like, http://www.example.com/student/login/3, my client want to cut the url like http://www.example.com/student/3, so I add code to routes.php

```
$route['student/(:any)'] = 'student/login/$1'
```

but it's not work, because every methods under Student controller will be effected, any tricks to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is said in [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#wildcards):

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

In that case you have to define your mo[re|st] specific routes before wildcard ones. For example:

```
$route['student/bcd'] = 'student/bcd';

$route['student/cde/(:num)'] = 'student/cde/$1';
//or even next one for this one
$route['student/(:num)'] = 'student/cde/$1';

$route['student/(:any)'] = 'student/login/$1';
```